# Change Data Values with User Values from form - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to change the values in my chart.js line chart with values that a user would populate in a form. The image below: (Ignore current placeholder data and value points). 
[Framework for graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBUSI.png)

I am fairly new to JS.
I am wondering how I can get the data to populate from the users' input for the forms, solely using JS, and no third party database/programs, etc.

The other thing is, I am building this in HubSpot so my JS code and HTML all have to be together in one custom HTML box.

Here is my code: 
**Thanks if you can help!**

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="350px" height="100px"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My Sales This Year',
            data: [10000, 15000, 4000, 11000, 15500, 10000, 8000, 10384],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

window.onload=function(){
    zingchart.render({
        id:"myChart",
        output:"svg",
        height:400,
        width:"100%",
        data:dataObj
    });
};
</script>

<form>
  Month:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Month"><br>
  Funnel Value:<br>
  <input type="number" name="Value">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: First question that comes to mind is: how will you rerender the data? Unless you persist data somewhere, you'll lose everything between reloads of the page (bad UX). Otherwise, I would look into [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) and use an array to keep the data entered with the form. Also, don't forget to prevent the default behavior of the submit button. What have you tried so far?